# Axios update value outside of then to break the loop

Tags: react-native, axios

I'm still currently learning on using React Native.

What I'm trying to do is update the limit value to 1 so it would break the while loop, but I am not sure on how to execute it since I can't update the value from inside the .then() in Axios POST call.
Glad if anyone would point out any method to handle this. Thank you for your help.

```
var limit = 0;
        while (limit == 0) {
          running = running + 20;
          console.log("restart");
          postDataCalories = {
            "query": `${running} minutes run and ${walking} minutes walking`,
            "gender":"male",
            // "nf_calories": 363.62,
            "weight_kg":63.5,
            "height_cm":167.64,
            "age":30
          };
          console.log(`${running} minutes run and ${walking} minutes walking`);
          axios.post('https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise', postDataCalories, axiosConfig2)
          .then((res3) => {
            console.log("exercise RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res3);
            let caloriesFood = res2.data.foods[0].nf_calories;
            let caloriesExercise = res3.data.exercises[0].nf_calories;
            let caloriesDifferences = caloriesFood - caloriesExercise;
            console.log("hi " + caloriesDifferences);
            if (caloriesDifferences < 50){
              console.log('done');
              limit = 1;
            } else {
              console.log('nope');
            }
          })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right in your case you cannot break the while loop inside the then-function  because that function is called at a different moment in time (they call it asynchronous).

There are two things you can do. If you have access to await/async in your environment you could rewrite it to:

```
async someFunction() { 
        var limit = 0;
        var running = 1;  // arbitrarily start at 1.
        while (limit == 0) {
          running = running + 20;
          console.log("restart running " + running);
          postDataCalories = {
            "query": `${running} minutes run and ${walking} minutes walking`,
            "gender":"male",
            // "nf_calories": 363.62,
            "weight_kg":63.5,
            "height_cm":167.64,
            "age":30
          };
          console.log(`${running} minutes run and ${walking} minutes walking`);
          var res3 = await axios.post('https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise', postDataCalories, axiosConfig2)

            console.log("exercise RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res3);
            let caloriesFood = res2.data.foods[0].nf_calories;
            let caloriesExercise = res3.data.exercises[0].nf_calories;
            let caloriesDifferences = caloriesFood - caloriesExercise;
            console.log("hi " + caloriesDifferences);
            if (caloriesDifferences < 50){
              console.log('done');
              limit = 1;
              // you may also do:
              break;
            } else {
              console.log('nope');
            }
          }
        }
}
```

For usual web conditions it requires either a modern browser (Firefox/Chrome) (or when you have babel / regenerator-runtime might do the trick, maybe your setup is already capable of transpiling this/running this.)

If you dont have access to async/await then you need to apply recursion (to work around the synchronicity). Normally you can perform the tasks sequentially (in a row, step by step, using a while loop), now you would write something like:

```
function runTheLoop(running, walking) {
          postDataCalories = {
            "query": `${running} minutes run and ${walking} minutes walking`,
            "gender":"male",
            // "nf_calories": 363.62,
            "weight_kg":63.5,
            "height_cm":167.64,
            "age":30
          };
          console.log(`${running} minutes run and ${walking} minutes walking`);
          axios.post('https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise', postDataCalories, axiosConfig2)
          .then((res3) => {
            console.log("exercise RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res3);
            let caloriesFood = res2.data.foods[0].nf_calories;
            let caloriesExercise = res3.data.exercises[0].nf_calories;
            let caloriesDifferences = caloriesFood - caloriesExercise;
            console.log("hi " + caloriesDifferences);
            if (caloriesDifferences < 50){
              console.log('done');
              // limit = 1;
              return;
            } else {
              console.log('nope');
 
              // This is the recursive variant of "running the loop again"
              return runTheLoop(running + 20, walking + 20);
            }
          })
        }
    }


// Somewhere:
console.log("restart");
// one minute of walking and one minute of running.
runTheLoop(1, 1);
```

Note: I've used your your code to make the examples relevant in to your situation, I could not test it out myself so it may not work directly if you copy and paste this.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for sharing your workaround with me, sir. I did try the async await alternative one, but it seems that the limit still won't break the loop and it keeps going on and on. I have a question, am I able to update the value of running under the "if (caloriesDifferences < 50)" statement?  Because it seems like I am unable to do that as there's no changes when I console.log the value. @JoshuaAngnoe

Comment: If it keeps on going sequentially (one after the other) then we are pretty close! Yes you may change the running variable, but I would suspect that on each loop running should increase with 20, if that is not the case then we may have done something wrong. The other thing you could do is instead of breaking via limit = 1 you may also use the 'break;'  statement. I'll update the code samples to show it.

Comment: Actually, I did make it work by messing around with the async/await method. Thank you very much for your detailed explanation on what and this works, sir! @JoshuaAngnoe